# list styles and text-decoration not working css, html

Tags: html, css

So I'm working on a project and I'm making a menu for the template.
But one thing is driving me crazy! And I searched for two hours or something and just couldn't find the solution, here's the problem:
I'm making a menu and the list-style-type and text-decoration are not working for some reason?
Here's the html and css code:

```css
.menu li {
 list-style-type: none;
}

.menu a {
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none; 
}
```

```html
           <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Galerij</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
```

The last times similar code worked. So I'm literally pulling my hair out.

Comment: it seems to work in the snippet. isn't that the result you are looking for?

Comment: Yes I did that already for some reason it doesn't work in the browser though. But it's not something in the link because I can change fonts

Comment: Code works for me. Explain your problem better.

Comment: All the properties you have aplied is is working properly in snippet. if it is external CSS check it first. Its better if you can show us your complete code, if there is no thousands lines.

Comment: If you can't reproduce the problem here it will be difficult to help you. Please try to reproduce it here.

Comment: What does your file structure look like? Is your `<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/css/file.css">` pointed correctly to your css file?

Answer (score 0):

`list-style-type: initial` and `text-decoration: underline` are their default values. Use these to turn them *on*.

```css
.menu li {
 list-style-type: initial;
}

.menu a {
 display: block;
 text-decoration: underline; 
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Galerij</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: Question wasn't clear.  Now OPS problem is unknown as hasn't reproduced here yet.

Comment: More information has been revealed in comments since my answer clarifying some things but making my answer not pertinent.

Comment: Keep remeber to ask in a comment before add an answer only if you couldnt understand..

Comment: You are correct, sir. I assumed I knew his intentions. Asking first would have been the better choice of action.